# Is the value= part of an HTML input checkbox required or can the value itself suffice

Tags: javascript, html, forms, prettier

I notice then when I am writing HTML, e.g., in a svelte template, that the prettier formatter that I have configured for my editor always removes the `value=` part so that

```
<label>                                                                
<input                                                               
   type="checkbox"                                                    
   bind:group={foo.bar}                    
   name="bar"                                          
   value={value} <———                                                           
/>                                                                   
 {value}                                                              
</label>
```

gets turned into

```
<label>                                                                
<input                                                               
   type="checkbox"                                                    
   bind:group={foo.bar}                    
   name="bar"                                          
   {value} <——-                                                           
/>                                                                   
 {value}                                                              
</label>
```

and yet when I look up the `input type=‘checkbox’` element reference docs on MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox, it doesn’t say `value=` is optional. I am using the input in a form and I thought it was necessary to have `value=`. Of course, empirically I can test this, but I haven’t yet. I am curious to hear what you may share about this.

Comment: That looks like [object property shorthand notation](https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/). You can do that because the property and the variable have the same name, if the variable didn't have the name `value` then you'd need to do `value={variable}`. But I haven't used Svelte before so cannot confirm 100% (it's something that you cannot do in HTML directly).

Comment: With slightly more elaborate docs over on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the attribute is required in HTML. The thing is that the code that you are sharing may look like HTML, but it is not. It is an HTML-looking JavaScript expression that will later be processed by Svelte and turned into actual HTML.

In the [Svelte documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#Attributes_and_props) they explain what you are seeing:

> When the attribute name and value match (`name={name}`), they can be replaced with `{name}`.
>
> ```
> <!-- These are equivalent -->
> <button disabled={disabled}>...</button>
> <button {disabled}>...</button>
> ```

That's the reason why your editor removes the `value={value}` and reduces it to just `{value}`: because **the property and the variable with the value have the same name**.

If you were using actual HTML, then you wouldn't be able to omit the property name and would need to write the whole thing `value="value"` (notice that it would be with quotes instead of curly braces.)